# Issue with rendering data based on role in Symfony/Twig

Tags: symfony5.4

> Hello,
>
> I'm currently working on a Symfony project where I need to render a list of "mededelingens" (announcements) based on the user's role. I have two routes, one for "leerling" (student) and one for "instructeur" (instructor), and I'm using the findBy method to retrieve the appropriate data from the MededelingenRepository.
>
> However, I'm encountering an issue where the loop in the Twig template does not display any data.
> I suspect there might be an error in the code related to passing the "rol" parameter to the findBy method.

```
/**
 * @Route("/leerling/mededelingen", name="app_leerling")
 */
public function show(MededelingenRepository $mededelingenRepository) {
    $mededelingen = $mededelingenRepository->findBy(["rol" => '["ROLE_LEERLING"]']);

    return $this->render('leerling/mededelingen.html.twig',
        ['mededelingen' => $mededelingen]
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/instructeur/mededelingen", name="app_instructeur")
 */
public function show(MededelingenRepository $mededelingenRepository) {
    $mededelingen = $mededelingenRepository->findBy(["rol" => '["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"]']);

    return $this->render('instructeur/mededelingen.html.twig',
        ['mededelingen' => $mededelingen]
    );
}

{% for mededelingens in mededelingen %}
    <p>{{ mededelingens.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}

$builder->add('rol', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices'  => [
        '["ROLE_LEERLING"]' => ["ROLE_LEERLING"],
        '["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"]' => ["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has been rewritten .

```
/**
     * @Route("/leerling/mededelingen", name="app_leerling")
     */ public function show(MededelingenRepository $mededelingenRepository) {
        $mededelingen = $mededelingenRepository->findBy(["rol" => '["ROLE_LEERLING"]']);

        return $this->render('leerling/mededelingen.html.twig',
            [ 'mededelingen' => $mededelingen,
        ]);
    }



/**
     * @Route("/instructeur/mededelingen", name="app_instructeur")
     */ public function show(MededelingenRepository $mededelingenRepository) {
        $mededelingen = $mededelingenRepository->findBy(["rol" => '["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"]']);

        return $this->render('instructeur/mededelingen.html.twig',
            [ 'mededelingen' => $mededelingen,
        ]);
    }
    
    {% for mededelingens in mededelingen %}

    <p> {{ mededelingens.name }} </p>

    {% endfor %}
    
    
    
    $builder->add('rol', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    '["ROLE_LEERLING"]' => ["ROLE_LEERLING"],
                    '["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"]' => ["ROLE_INSTRUCTEUR"],
                ],
            ]);
```